# How would I store notes from a midi file so that I can visualize them quickly?

Tags: lua, love2d

I have made myself a Midi file reader in pure Lua and I decided that I would make a visualizer in love2d and So I did first I made it display the currently playing notes by looping through them and deciding which ones were on.

That worked fine and I constantly got around 300fps but then I decided I wanted a preview kinda like the synthesia program but I'm having a hard time thinking of a good way to store them so that I don't have to loop through each note per pixel to decide which are on (this method makes it go at about 15-30fps) at the time in the future (or past).

I have tried making a table with indexes as the time in seconds and the values tables with the current notes that are on but I cant seem to make it work. If anyone has any suggestions as to how I would store and access these notes from variables quickly your help would be really appreciated. (also I know I can use C or C++ or a library but I want to make one in pure Lua)

The notes are currently stored in a table of notes that are only in chronological order by track so like track1note1, track1note2, track1note3, track2note2 etc...

The table is structured like this

```
    table = {
--{start time(in seconds),end time(in seconds),note,track,velocity}, note1
{0.00043,1.387289,44,1,127},--note2
--etc...
}
```

Comment: I can give the code or parts of it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having a hard time thinking of  a good way to store them so that I don't have to loop through each note *per pixel*

How about looping through each pixel **per note**? Your first solution looks fine to me:

```
for i = start, #note_table do
    local t0, t1, note, track, vel = unpack(note_table[i])

    -- break the loop if the current note is fully off-screen

    -- draw the note number 'i' in here,
    -- highlight the corresponding piano key, etc.
end
```

Since you mentioned the table is sorted chronologically, by carefully selecting the `start` index you'll only draw the notes you need.

Addressing the original question, you can reduce the memory usage by grouping each note attribute in it's own table. This *may* gain net a slight performance gain. eg.

```
note_table = {
    t0   = { ... },
    t1   = { ... },
    note = { ... },
    -- etc...
}
```

Nevertheless, if you are looking for something more involved, you should take a look at [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).